# apache setting to not allow any files to execute within specific sub-directory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a sub-directory within the html/ doc root that users need to upload images to.  I need to set up something so that no scripts (php) can be executed within this directory.  There will be multiple users uploading images to this directory but just in case one of their accounts is compromised I'd like to add some added protection so that a malicious script cannot be executed.  The directory is only for serving up images.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
<Directory /foo/bar>
  [other directives for this dir]
  AddHandler default-handler .php 
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I added the following new directory container to the Apache.conf file for the specific directory:

```
<Directory /www/sites/www.example.com/html/images>
RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3 .php5
RemoveType .php .phtml .php3 .php5
php_flag engine off
</Directory>
```

source: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=354749.0

Answer (score 0):

Use `AddHandler` in a `<Directory>` section to force PHP scripts to go through `default-handler`.

Comment: can you please clarify?

Comment: ... Which part?